# How to deal with Microsoft Azure error during authorization?

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-virtual-machine

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests

client_id = *CLIENT_ID*
client_secret = *CLIENT_SECRET*
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token =oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/*TENANT_ID*/oauth2/token', auth=auth,resource= 'https://management.azure.com/')

data = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
r =requests.post('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'
             '*SUBSCRIPTION_ID*/providers/Microsoft.Compute/'
             'locations/eastus/vmSizes?api-version=2016-04-30-preview', headers=data)
```

I'm trying to get list of available VM's, but I'm getting an error:

{'error': {'code': 'AuthorizationFailed', 'message': "The client 'X' with object id 'X' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/locations/vmSizes/read' over scope '/subscriptions/Y'."}}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the api you used method is `get` not `post`.

Secondly, **you need give your sp `Owner` role, according to the error log, you don't give enough permission to your service principal**, please see this [link:assign-application-to-role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

[image]

I test in my lab, the following code works for me.

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests

client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token =oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennat id>/oauth2/token', auth=auth,resource= 'https://management.azure.com/')


data = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
r =requests.get('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/eastus/vmSizes?api-version=2016-04-30-preview', headers=data)
for i in r:
    print i
```

Comment: @ShengbaoShuiMSFT Could you check my printscreen, please. I haven't got window with roles

Comment: @Ernst Hi, see this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/tvsR8 You should give `Owner` or `Contributor` role to your service principal.

Comment: @ShengbaoShuiMSFT Hello, I've already gave myself permissions as contributor and owner - [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/33ICK) . It doesn't work as I can choose only `Role` and `Assign access to`

Comment: @Ernst Hi, https://imgur.com/a/QyQyV  In the `select  Dialog box`. Type your sp name or application or(your client id). Then you will find your sp.

Comment: @Ernst Do you see `Search by name or e-mail address`? Type your `client id`, then you will get your service principal.  Then click `Save`.  Like this screenshot  https://imgur.com/a/ncpCQ

Comment: @ShengbaoShuiMSFT  Thank you very much! Now it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164674/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-ernst).